# How to keep assets file import statement when assets file is too bigger to transform by @rollup/plugin-url?

Tags: reactjs, rollup

I import a img(92KB), it is bigger than 14KB(default limit from `@rollup/plugin-url`). So the img won't be tranformed to base64, after rollup bundle, the img import statement transformed to `var projectSelector = "bf30b7d903c67955.png";`.

> The bundle will be published as a npm package.

```js
// source code
import projectSelector from './assets/market-project-selector.png';

function App() {
   return (
    <>
      <img src={projectSelector} alt={'projectLogo'} />
    </>
   );
}

// output
var projectSelector = "bf30b7d903c67955.png";

function App() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(React.Fragment, null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("img", {
    src: projectSelector,
    alt: 'projectLogo'
  }));
}
```

My rollup config:

```js
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';

export default {
   input: 'src/index.js',
   output: {
      file: 'public/bundle.js',
      format: 'es'
   },
   external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
   plugins: [
      nodeResolve({
         extensions: ['.js', 'jsx']
      }),
      babel({
         babelHelpers: 'bundled',
         presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
         extensions: ['.js']
      }),
      commonjs(),
      replace({
         preventAssignment: false,
         'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"'
      }),
      url()
   ]
}
```

I want the img import statement is transformed to like `import projectSelector from './assets/bf30b7d903c67955.png';`

I read `@rollup/plugin-url` doc and `rollup` doc, but I don't find relevant config options.